# Tab Widget and Listview combo

Tags: android, listview, tabwidget

Howdy, I am trying to combine the [TabWidget](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) and [ListView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) Tutorials. Also I added a couple of buttons with no functions right now. Each tab is supposed to be a ListView (for right now). I run the app and it launches as just a ListView and no tabs. Here is the main.xml used in TabaWidget.java:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/MainMenu"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Main Menu" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Sort"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Sort" />
   </LinearLayout>
<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

If the problem doesn't lye in there, then I can post other code as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Considering that there is no `ListView` in your layout, I find it rather difficult to believe that you are actually loading this layout file in your code. Here is a sample project demonstrating a `TabHost` containing a `ListView` on one tab: http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtutorials/tree/master/06-Tabs/

Comment: I have this layout file and another for list_item.xml just like the tutorial showed. From what I understand, I use the main.xml for the tab and list_item.xml for the specific listview inside the tab. I appreciate the sample though.